# URL from Uber API's /v1/requests/{request_id}/map endpoint does not work

Tags: uber-api

I am hitting /v1/requests/{request_id}/map while a person is in a Uber ride using my registered Uber app. The end-point returns a url like: https://trip.uber.com/xxxxxxxx, but when i try opening it I get a 404 error and am being redirected to https://www.uber.com/404/. I am using Uber in India, if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Are you opening the link as soon as the ride request is made? Unfortunately the link is broken until a driver accepts the request. After that it should work.

This is a known issue in the API.

Comment: No. I am opening after the ride is accepted. The documentation states this clear enough that the link will work only after ride is accepted.

Comment: Turns out this is a regression on Uber's side. We're working on it and will release a fix soon. Sorry about that!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! When it is fixed, how would I know ?

Comment: It's fixed now. In general we tweet out incident updates as @UberDevelopers but this one was resolved before we started tweeting.